# Display instances of images in a 5x2 square?

Tags: php, html, css

i want to display 10 instances of an image in a 5x2 square. I coded this in PHP/HTML/CSS:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    if ($i >= 5) {
      $top_position=780;
      echo "1". "<br />";
    }else {
      $top_position = 430;
      echo "2". "<br />";       
    }

    if ($i >= 5) {
      $u = 20 + 250 * $i - 250 * 5;
    }
    else {
      $u = 20 + 250 * $i;
    }

    echo "<style> " . ".background" . $u . "{" . "position: absolute;
   left: " . $u . "px;" . "top: " . $top_position . "px;" . "</style>";
    echo "<img src=http://localhost/Summoner's%20Index/images/scheme.png class=background" . $u . ">";}
```

I get an 5x1 in the second row, and as text i get: 1111122222, so it seems as if the programm would work properly. Why do i just get 5images and not 10?

Comment: are you looking out for 2 lines of squares, 5 in each line?

Comment: yeah, 2 lines with 5 instances of the image each line.

Comment: You can put the style in a `style=""` attribute instead of declaring a `<style>`, `<style>` should be used only in `<head>`. *Why do i just get 5images and not 10* There is 10 numbers/images, not 5, what is your question?

Comment: @A.L well it works formatted this way, it is just that the image only gtes displayed 5times..

Comment: @bastianum check out the code below if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the code below:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo "<img src=http://localhost/Summoner's%20Index/images/scheme.png class=background" . $u . ">";

    if ($i == 5){
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: `echo "<br>";` does not work for images, this code doesn't work :/

Comment: yeah, grid 5x2. that doesn't work, it doens't position the image correctly.

Comment: @bastianum please upload the image of the final output. I need to see how it is getting displayed.

Comment: thanks mate, but i solved it. i always overwrote the styles, because $u just went till 1020 and after that it got resetted.

Comment: @bastianum glad you got it. Request to mark the answer as correct as it would help others as well..